# Script doesn't run React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file

I am trying to run a separate file with React.js code.

But when I am trying to run the file it does not work. The page is just a blank. If I do every in the HTML file in-line scripting it works just fine.

I want to have my html file like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>React - Projekt</title>
    <script src="../../js/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../js/react-dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../js/browser.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../js/albums.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="container"></div>

    <script type="text/babel" src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

and my js file:

```
var Albums = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="albums">
                {this.state.albums.map(function(album, index) {
                    return (
                        <Album
                            album={album}
                            onClick={this.removeAlbum.bind(this, index)}
                            />
                    )
                }, this)}
            </div>
        )
    }
});

// Rendera the shit innehåll
ReactDOM.render(
    <Albums />,
    document.getElementById("container")
);
```

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: You need to run it from a web server. There are many options available, like [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) or a [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb?hl=en).

Comment: I made changes using  src="../../js/script.js
I get this error:
 browser.min.js:4 Failed to load file:///C:/Users/antonidag/src/demos/001/script.js: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Dose that have

Comment: Ah okay, so I actually have to run it from a web server?
Let's say I am using a web server, will the code work or I have to come up with another solution?

Comment: I recommend you to use [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) because you can focus on your application and on learning React and then you can dig into webpack to create a server and customize your build if you want

Comment: Okay, thank! I'll try that out! Pretty new to React, and there are many different ways to code! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load babel core Browser to load your `script.js` as `text/babel`

It will read your `script.js` and transform to JSX. Insert this after react-dom

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You mean inside my index.html file or my js file?
I tried to insert this in the head tag inside the index.html fil. But still gets the same error: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome.

Comment: Yes, inside your index.html at <head></head>.Are you opening the html file directly at browser ? You need to **test with a webserver like Nginx, Apache**. You can search for a hosting provider or Github pages.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I used Apache and now it's working!